# Button's IsEnabled works inadequate

Tags: wpf, button, isenabled

I make 'iconed button': Button and two TextBlock above (inside DockPanel). One TextBlock is 'icon' (w Awesome font), another is for text on button. **Problem:** when in VS designer I set `IsEnabled=false`, only second TextBlock become disabled - icon still has original color (no "disabled" look). WHY??

Unfortunately in clumsy C# you can override only what author allowed, so I had to create new 'IsEnabled' property:

```
public new bool IsEnabled
{
    get => base.IsEnabled;
    set {
        base.IsEnabled = value;
        txtIcon.Opacity = (value ? 1.0 : 0.4);
    }
}
```

But again if in XAML I set `IsEnabled=false`, icon doesn't become disabled. And only when **in code** I set `btnOK.IsEnabled=false`, a whole button has disabled look.
I completely lost in this clumsy behaviour - even when I force button to make "disabled look" for icon, it's still misbehaves in VS designer (does designer set some another 'IsEnabled'??).
Any ideas? (ideally if I don't need to override 'IsEnabled')

SOLUTION

It seems if you set `Foreground` for a TextBlock, WPF check it and does nothing to make it look disabled (again WHY??). So you have to manually change appearance of your TextBlock. Best approach is to set Opacity property of TextBlock to smth like 0.3 if parent Button is disabled:

```
var b = new Binding {
    // ElementName = "btnOK",
    Source = btnOK,
    Path = new PropertyPath("IsEnabled"),
};
b.Converter = new OpacityConv();// converts bool to 1.0 or 0.3
txtIcon.SetBinding(TextBlock.OpacityProperty, b);
```

Comment: Why??? You've not thought about how is enabled changes anything else in your button. You need to bind to the same brush is being changed or use a trigger to change the fill of your icon.

Comment: "Any ideas?" - it is possible to disable designer in VS, and see only xaml markup. clumsy, but that is what you get without a [mcve]

Comment: @ASh: you don't need so much to reproduce - just drop two TextBlock on a Button and see. Sorry, problematic code is split on lib & app, it takes too much to make separate example. But I described problem well.

Comment: So if you directly set Foreground of TextBlock, that value will prevail. There is nothing strange.

Comment: @emoacht: so you're not confused that TextBlock sit as a child of disabled control? OK, I got your level.

Comment: In most cases, the local value will prevail in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your approach to:

### Xaml:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="50">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <!-- Icon -->
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="..." Width="16" Height="16"/>
    
    <!-- Text -->
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="text"/>
</Grid>
```

But even if it doesn't work, you can always change the colour of the text!

Workaround

Comment: Sorry, @Renato, I cannot use <Image> - it is TextBlock and MUST work, because both controls are equal (except font).